# tricontour is not compatible with matlab version, or octave clabel

Tags: octave

I  need to draw and label contours  of data given on a Delaunay grid.  The function tricontour, part of the apparently no longer supported plot pkg, cannot do this, because the function returns a single argument (h):

```
pkg load plot
nx=ny=11;
[x,y]=ndgrid(linspace(-1,1,nx),linspace(-1,1,ny));
xp=[x(:),y(:)];
tp=[1,2,nx+1;nx+2,nx+1,2];
tp=kron(tp,ones(ny-1,1))+kron(ones(size(tp)),(0:ny-2)'*nx);
tp=kron(tp,ones(nx-1,1))+kron(ones(size(tp)),(0:nx-2)');
G=xp(:,1)+xp(:,2);
h=tricontour(tp,xp(:,1),xp(:,2),G,[-1:.5:1],'b');
[h]=clabel(c,h,[-4:2:6])
```

This MWE fails with

```
error: 'c' undefined near line 10 column 12
error: called from
Testricontourlabel at line 10 column 4
```

The matlab version of this function returns both c and h, and so is compatible with the matlab version of clabel.

Any ideas for a work around?

Comment: I am a little confused, are you talking about the octave function or one of the MATLAB file exchange submissions? All share the same name.

Comment: Sorry: I am comparing the octave function tricontour that is part of the octave package "plot" and is invoked with "h=tricontour(...)." with the matlab function "[c,h]=tricontour(...)". The absence of the return array c in the octave function makes it impossible to use either octave or matlab functions clabel to label contours.  Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: how about wrapping the octave function with one that returns both arguments?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what is meant by wrapping?  As far as I know the matrix c does not appear in the octave version of tricontour?  What would a code snippet look like?

Comment: I note that while octave plotting routines like trisurf and trimesh are part of the ongoing, updated octave plot library, the octave version of tricontour seems to live in a lonesome place of its own.  Is it possible that whoever maintains trisurf, trimesh etc.., could put tricontour under their wing?

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do, it sounds like you're trying to use the tricontour function from the octave package into matlab? in any case, I note that the 2,3,4 and 5th argument of the tricontour function are the same as the 1,2,3, and 4th argument of the contourc function, which returns your 'c'. Perhaps that's all you need. Unfortunately when I try it on your code it also informs me that "manual contour mode is not supported", not sure why. But perhaps you can work around that?

Comment: Could you rephrase this as an answer and show me what you mean with reference to the contourc function?  I had not looked at that.  BTW what I am trying to do is use octave functions only to plot and annotate contours, so if the octave tricontour workes similarly to the matlab version. I would follow a call to the (octave) tricontour with a call to the (octave) clabel.  Hope this helps. PS I have edited the original MWE to remove the "manual" argument.  The basic question remains: why is octave version of tricontour incompatible with the matlab version